# R programming how to apply individual elements in list to a function

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply, tapply

I have a list with multiple elements, I need to apply ets function from forecast using two elements from each list.

Below is the list dat.list each list has time series called `z` and a `lam`

```
## Create Dummy list
##Time series -> z, lambda - > lam
z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(30,10,10), 100, 3), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
lam <- 0.8
ap <- list(z=z,lam=lam)


z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(30,10,10), 100, 3), start = c(1971, 1), frequency = 12)
lam <- 0.5
zp <- list(z=z,lam=lam)

dat.list <- list(ap=ap,zp=zp)
```

Now I need take each time series `z` and take `lam` and apply it with `ets` function from `forecast` package. I used the following code.

```
library("forecast")
library("plyr")   
ets.f <- function(x) {
      forecast(ets(x$z, lambda = x$lam),h=12)$mean ## I need to apply lambda from list lam
    }

    ens.f <- function(x){
      mm <- llply(x,ets.f)
      tq <- matrix(unlist(mm), ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
      tq
    }

    fore <- llply(dat.list, ens.f)
```

When I run the program i get the following error `"Error in x$z : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"`.

I'm not sure how to apply individual elements of a list and apply it to a function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much

Also, I also tried to separate `z` and `lam` in the list and was stuck on how to apply this. I'm apoen to using the code below as well. Thanks much appreciated.

```
ts.l <- lapply(dat.list,'[[','z')
lam.l <- lapply(dat.list,'[[','lam')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
lapply(dat.list, function(x) matrix(unlist(lapply(x$z,
           function(y) forecast(ets(y, lambda=x$lam), 
                        h=12)$mean)), ncol=12, byrow=TRUE))
```

Comment: hi @akrun, since I have many 1000's of matrices, I'm thinking of running it parallel. It would be great if you could modify the code above to change from lapply to parLapply using package `snow` in both the instances. I could also raise a separate questions. Many Thanks

Comment: @forecaster It would be better to have it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks akrun, I just posted it, I would live to hear your thoughts on it. Thanks